# Make node a revision of another node

Tags: 7, nodes

I have migrated content from a non-Drupal system to a fresh Drupal site. Some of the content nodes however should in fact be revisions of another node, not a unique node of themselves.  Is there any quick and easy way to turn a node into a revision of another node?

Comment: Hi Neil,
Looks like you have already found a solution since you neither commented  nor rewarded the bounty.
Please share your solution here so that it helps other users also.

Answer (score 0):

I have not come across such a scenario. However, here's a fairly simple method to achieve it:

1. Install the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module
2. Add an Entity Reference field to the content type of this node by navigating to Structure > Content Type > [the content type of these nodes] > Manage Fields
3. Choose the Target type as 'Node' & choose the same content type as the 'bundle'
4. Label this field as 'Revision of' (say)
5. Now, you can either choose to manually enter the 'nid' of the original node here or run a query in the database to fill this entity reference field with the nid of the original node.
6. For example, lets say the content type is 'test' & the entity reference field is 'field_revision_of'

   6.a. Write an insert query like this:
      insert into 'field_data_field_revision_of' set entity_type = 'node',bundle='test',deleted=0,entity_id = [nid of revision node],revision_id = [nid of revision node],language='und',delta=0,field_revision_of_target_id=[nid of original node];

   6.b. Since you should also update the database revision table of a field:
    insert into 'field_revision_field_revision_of' set entity_type = 'node',bundle='test',deleted=0,entity_id = [nid of revision node],revision_id = [nid of revision node],language='und',delta=0,field_revision_of_target_id=[nid of original node];

Let me know if this helps.

Regards,

Supriya Rajgopal

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is module for that, but it can be done with some custom coding. It is not quick and easy. It is also not a conventional way. You will have to write database queries to update data, which shouldn't be done if you don't know what you do. I won't write the whole code, but I'll outline the steps you need to take to convert a node's data into a revision of an another node.

#### Definitions

Let's define the wording for the rest of the answer.

- **Revision node:** A node to be converted into a revision of another node (*target node*).
- **Target node:** A node which will be the current revision of the converted node (*revision node*).
- A *target node* can have multiple *revision nodes*.

#### Outline

1. **BACKUP** your database and clear the caches.
2. At very first, you should have a list of node ids of *revision nodes*, and their *target nodes*. You'll need to map them in an array, with keys are the node ids of the *revision nodes*, and the values are the node ids of the *target nodes*.

   Let's assume you want that the *revision nodes* `10` and `11` should be revisions of the *target node* `3`, and the *revision node* `12` should be a revision of node `5`. Your mapping array should look like that:

   ```
   $revision_mapping = array(
     10 => 3,
     11 => 3,
     12 => 5,
   );
   ```
3. Having your revision mapping at hand, you should find all  `field_data_FIELD_NAME` tables in the database. A query as follows would do the job: `SHOW TABLES LIKE 'field_data_%';`. **Gotcha** if you have a db prefix, you should also bear in mind that in the queries.
4. After getting the field data table names into an array, you will loop through all those tables and query for the *revision nodes*. The query would look like as follows:

   ```
   $field_data = db_select($field_data_table, 'data')
     ->fields('data')
     ->condition('entity_type', 'node')
     ->condition('bundle', 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE')
     ->condition('entity_id', array_keys($revision_mapping), 'IN')
     ->execute()
     ->fetchAllAssoc('entity_id', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   ```
5. After getting the data for a field, you should (in the same loop) change the entity ids of the data into the node id of the *target node* and insert this data into corresponding `field_revision_FIELD_NAME` table.

   ```
   if ($field_data) {
     // Field revision table name from field data table
     $field_revision_table = str_replace('field_data_', 'field_revision_', $field_data_table);

     // Build insert query for field revision table
     $insert_query = db_insert($field_revision_table)
       ->fields(array_keys($field_data[0]));

     foreach ($field_data as $entity_id => $data) {
       // Update entity_id with the target node's node id.
       $data['entity_id'] = $revision_mapping[$entity_id];
       $insert_query->values($data);
     }

     $insert_query->execute();

     // Delete field data from data table
     db_delete($field_data_table)
       ->condition('entity_type', 'node')
       ->condition('bundle', 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE')
       ->condition('entity_id', array_keys($field_data), 'IN')
       ->execute();
   }
   ```
6. Update `node_revision` table:

   ```
   foreach ($revision_mapping as $revision => $target) {
     $db_update('node_revision)
        ->fields(array('nid' => $target))
        ->condition('nid', $revision)
        ->execute();
   ```

#### Notes

- Above instructions serve as an outline and takes only the field data into account. If your site has other modules enabled, which may also store the node ids in a separate table, those should also be updated. For example, if you have comments and flag modules enabled, you should consider to update `comment` and `flagging` tables respectively.
- I'd put this code in a [`hook_update_N`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7.x) of a custom module, and use [Batch API](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/batch_example!batch_example.install/function/batch_example_update_7100/7.x-1.x), since this may a long taking process if there are many nodes to be converted.
- You may consider deleting the *revision nodes* after the update. Or, you can use `node_delete_multiple(array_keys($revision_mapping))`.